# Can I hide or lock one drive for Acronis backups only?

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage

I have a 500 GB hard disk drive.
I am using [Acronis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronis_True_Image) to have backups over there.

Is there any way to hide that drive from Windows Explorer or make that drive only used by Acronis and other read only.

Just like what [Windows Backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_and_Restore_Center) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount the drive to an NTFS folder instead of a drive letter, as described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889

The *folder* would be visible in Explorer, but you wouldn't see it listed as another drive.

Comment: You can also set NTFS permissions on the folder so only the user that the Acronis backups are running as are able to write to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows XP, then using [Tweak UI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) is your best option.  See these [instructions](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/how-to-hide-confidential-hard-disk-drive-in-windows/) on how to hide a drive from Explorer.

Or if you are using a Professional or higher level of Vista or 7 then you can configure a group policy to hide the drive.  See these [instructions](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Hide-Drive-Appearing-Windows-Explorer_t15123.html), they are for XP but the policy still exists in Windows 7.

Both of these make Explorer not list the drive, but it is still accessible if you type the drive letter in the address bar.